# How to label and refer to appendix correctly

Tags: appendix, number

I am writing a report and I've tried to solve this problem by looking at other similar questions, however I'm not able to find a question matching mine exactly.

All I want is to refer to something in my appendix. However, when I label it and then refer to it in the text, it refers to it wrongly.

For instance, I want to refer to this:
[image]

I'm not sure why it is called "B.0" instead of "B.1" however, it's not the main problem.
My coding for this is:

```
\refstepcounter{section}% 
\includepdf[pages={1}, pagecommand=\chapter{Appendix: Tjeklister}\section*{\thesection \quad Ellagic Acid Ameliorates Lung Inflammation and Heart Oxidative Stress in Elastase-Induced Emphysema Model in Rat}, scale=0.71, offset=0 -3cm]{Bilag/artikel1CASP.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={2-3}, pagecommand={}]{Bilag/artikel1CASP.pdf}
\label{artikel1}
```

Bonus info: I've done a lot of mixed coding since I wanted to include pdf-files, bring them on the same page as the header, resize it, remove page number and remove it from the list of contents without removing the appendix numbering. Maybe the problem is to be found in here?

When I refer to it in the text with

```
\ref{artikel1}
```

It is shown as;

[image]

However, there is no A.5 in the appendix? How do I get overleaf to refer to it correctly?

Please let me know if I need to include anything in this question, I just started using this website for help :)

Comment: Please post a complete example code that can be used to reproduce the problem. Without that, it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: the \chapter command will reset the section counter, and also change the reference.

Comment: @IanThompson Thanks for commenting. Since I am new here, I am not sure, what a complete example code includes? Are you asking for more coding from the main.tex related do the appendix? Something from preamble? Or anything else?

Comment: See [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/2417).

Comment: Do you still need help with this? If so, please follow the link in my earlier comment to see what we need in order to answer. As it stands, this question can't be answered and is at risk of being closed.

Comment: @IanThompson Hi, thanks for the help. We decided to write it manually and not use the ref, since we reached a deadline and had to prioritize the issues. But I will take the advice and the linked question into consideration when creating a new question in the future